# using jquery $.ajax to call a PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This may be a simple answer, but I'm using jQuery's $.ajax to call a PHP script. What I want to do is basically put that PHP script inside a function and call the PHP function from javascript.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['something'] {
    //do something
}
?>
```

to this

```
<?php
function test() {
    if(isset($_POST['something'] {
         //do something. 
    }
}
?>
```

How would i call that function in javascript? Right now i'm just using $.ajax with the PHP file listed.

Comment: Passing PHP javascript-generated PHP code to be eval'd, or doing it the other way around, is a **very** bad idea.

Comment: Can you explain why that's bad?

Comment: Because ANYONE can put ANY code in place of your code, and thus they can do bad things to your server.

Comment: @Chacha102: Either you or me don't understand the question. In my understanding he wants to do a remote procedure call.

Comment: A remote procedure call could be acceptable if you had a whitelist in place that restricts access to all but your allowed functions or "procedures". This would not be difficult to implement.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Use `$.ajax` to call a server context (or URL, or whatever) to invoke a particular 'action'.  What you want is something like:

```
$.ajax({ url: '/my/site',
         data: {action: 'test'},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                      alert(output);
                  }
});
```

On the server side, the `action` POST parameter should be read and the corresponding value should point to the method to invoke, e.g.:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'test' : test();break;
        case 'blah' : blah();break;
        // ...etc...
    }
}
```

I believe that's a simple incarnation of the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Comment: Gotcha. So you can't directly choose with js which function to call in PHP, you can only use PHP to grab the post value and call a function that way. Thanks

Comment: But this is simple if you are using a framework. with Kohana for example you can simply call the controller/action
ajax(function(){
url:'Controller/action.php',
});

Comment: @MrMesees It would be great if you share those modern best-practices with us.

Comment: using HTTP fetch API could be for the JS frontend, as well as using promises. For PHP sanitizing and filtering input, perhaps using a middleware so that it can be applied to multiple endpoints. I suppose importantly if you'd like my feedback not waiting ~2 years might be a great option.

Answer (score 12):

I developed a jQuery plugin that allows you to call any core PHP function or even user defined PHP functions as methods of the plugin: [jquery.php](https://github.com/Xaxis/jqueryphp)

After including jquery and jquery.php in the head of our document and placing request_handler.php on our server we would start using the plugin in the manner described below.

For ease of use reference the function in a simple manner:

```
    var P = $.fn.php;
```

Then initialize the plugin:

```
P('init', 
{
    // The path to our function request handler is absolutely required
    'path': 'http://www.YourDomain.com/jqueryphp/request_handler.php',

    // Synchronous requests are required for method chaining functionality
    'async': false,

    // List any user defined functions in the manner prescribed here
            // There must be user defined functions with these same names in your PHP
    'userFunctions': {

        languageFunctions: 'someFunc1 someFunc2'
    }
});
```

And now some usage scenarios:

```
// Suspend callback mode so we don't work with the DOM
P.callback(false);

// Both .end() and .data return data to variables
var strLenA = P.strlen('some string').end();
var strLenB = P.strlen('another string').end();
var totalStrLen = strLenA + strLenB;
console.log( totalStrLen ); // 25

// .data Returns data in an array
var data1 = P.crypt("Some Crypt String").data();
console.log( data1 ); // ["$1$Tk1b01rk$shTKSqDslatUSRV3WdlnI/"]
```

Demonstrating PHP function chaining:

```
var data1 = P.strtoupper("u,p,p,e,r,c,a,s,e").strstr([], "C,A,S,E").explode(",", [], 2).data();
var data2 = P.strtoupper("u,p,p,e,r,c,a,s,e").strstr([], "C,A,S,E").explode(",", [], 2).end();
console.log( data1, data2 );
```

Demonstrating sending a JSON block of PHP pseudo-code:

```
var data1 = 
        P.block({
    $str: "Let's use PHP's file_get_contents()!",
    $opts: 
    [
        {
            http: {
                method: "GET",
                header: "Accept-language: en\r\n" +
                        "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
            }
        }
    ],
    $context: 
    {
        stream_context_create: ['$opts']
    },
    $contents: 
    {
        file_get_contents: ['http://www.github.com/', false, '$context']
    },
    $html: 
    {
        htmlentities: ['$contents']
    }
}).data();
    console.log( data1 );
```

The backend configuration provides a whitelist so you can restrict which functions can be called. There are a few other patterns for working with PHP described by the plugin as well.

Answer (score 5):

I would stick with normal approach to call the file directly, but if you really want to call a function, have a look at [**JSON-RPC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) (JSON Remote Procedure Call).

You basically send a JSON string in a specific format to the server, e.g.

```
{ "method": "echo", "params": ["Hello JSON-RPC"], "id": 1}
```

which includes the function to call and the parameters of that function.

Of course the server has to know how to handle such requests.
Here is [jQuery plugin for JSON-RPC](https://github.com/hagino3000/jquery-jsonrpc2.0) and e.g. the [Zend JSON Server](http://framework.zend.com/manual/de/zend.json.server.html) as server implementation in PHP.

---

This might be overkill for a small project or less functions. Easiest way would be [karim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function/2269397#2269397). On the other hand, JSON-RPC is a standard.

Answer (score 4):

You can't call a PHP function with Javascript, in the same way you can't call arbitrary PHP functions when you load a page (just think of the security implications).

If you need to wrap your code in a function for whatever reason, why don't you either put a function call under the function definition, eg:

```
function test() {
    // function code
}

test();
```

Or, use a PHP include:

```
include 'functions.php'; // functions.php has the test function
test();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are going to have to expose and endpoint (URL) in your system which will accept the POST request from the ajax call in jQuery.

Then, when processing that url from PHP, you would call your function and return the result in the appropriate format (JSON most likely, or XML if you prefer).

Answer (score 3):

You may use my library that does that automatically, I've been improving it for the past 2 years http://phery-php-ajax.net

```php
Phery::instance()->set(array(
   'phpfunction' => function($data){
      /* Do your thing */
      return PheryResponse::factory(); // do your dom manipulation, return JSON, etc
   }
))->process();
```

The javascript would be simple as

```js
phery.remote('phpfunction');
```

You can pass all the dynamic javascript part to the server, with a query builder like chainable interface, and you may pass any type of data back to the PHP. For example, some functions that would take too much space in the javascript side, could be called in the server using this (in this example, mcrypt, that in javascript would be almost impossible to accomplish):

```js
function mcrypt(variable, content, key){
  phery.remote('mcrypt_encrypt', {'var': variable, 'content': content, 'key':key || false});
}

//would use it like (you may keep the key on the server, safer, unless it's encrypted for the user)
window.variable = '';
mcrypt('variable', 'This must be encoded and put inside variable', 'my key');
```

and in the server

```php
Phery::instance()->set(array(
  'mcrypt_encrypt' => function($data){
     $r = new PheryResponse;

     $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
     $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
     $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $data['key'] ? : 'my key', $data['content'], MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
     return $r->set_var($data['variable'], $encrypted);
     // or call a callback with the data, $r->call($data['callback'], $encrypted);
  }
))->process();
```

Now the `variable` will have the encrypted data.