# How to call a php function from javascript by specify its name

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call PHP Function using jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152431/call-php-function-using-jquery-ajax)
>   [Call php function from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165395/call-php-function-from-javascript)

*I need*

```
callPhpFnc("myPhp"); // javascript function
```

how can i call the php function with myPhp as function name.

*in my php file*

```
<?php
 function myPhp()
 {
     echo 'Hello';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible my dear. Coz your php is runned once at server side before the page is loaded. But the javascript at client side. Option is to use the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You cant call a PHP function by JS.You have to use ajax for this.

Comment: You mean pass the function name as GET or POST method and call in PHP file?

Comment: You can pass any perimeter to the PHP file which will indicate it to call the function you want to.