# Is it possible to call specific PHP function from mainfunction.php file through Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call PHP Function using jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152431/call-php-function-using-jquery-ajax)

I have a PHP file containing all functions created by me. I just want to know, how can I call a specific function through Ajax?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with this. You can only AJAX call a URL. You would need to have the functions at a separate URL or use some MVC framework to map them

Comment: If you have a different `URL` for each of the methods, you can call those urls to call the methods associated with them

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a get or post variable and use it to then using php call a specific function. WHat exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

send the function name through GET method to the php page and then execute _GET value using `call_user_func`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
$name = $_POST['function'];

if (in_array($name, $allowed_functions)) {
    $result = call_user_func($name);
}
```

Although this reeks of bad design. Why do you need to do this?