# declaring/calling php function from another file using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, function

How do I call my functions from functions.php to html.php with the use of AJAX?  I want to declare my functions inside my html.php file without using include or require. only ajax pls. Thanks allot! see below

functions.php

```
<?php
function samplefunc(){ 
   echo "Hello world"; 
}
?>
```

html.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php samplefunc(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152431/call-php-function-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: There are a lot tutorials available in internet. Please do a Google before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

add the below code in html.php

```
$.post("functions.php", {call_function: samplefunc})
                .done(function(response) {
alert(response);
}
```

and add below code in functions.php

```
function samplefunc() {
    echo 'Answer';
}

if ($_POST['call_function'] == "samplefunc") {
    samplefunc();
}
```