# call form php a function inside jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i'd like to call a jquery function from php.
I tried this way, but the jquery functions are not called.

jq.action.js

```
$(function() {

  $("#reset" ).click(function(e){       
    e.preventDefault();
    reset_fields();
  });

  function reset_fields(){
    $(":input").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  }

  function error_msg(){
    alert("Error");
  }

});
```

index.php

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jq.action.js'></script> 

<?php
if ($_POST['id'] == '1') {

       echo '<script>reset_fields();</script>';

} else {

       echo '<script>error_msg();</script>';
}
?>
```

**ReferenceError: reset_fields is not defined**

how can I call from php the functions inside jquery? thanks!

Comment: You cannot call jquery functions directly from PHP. PHP is server sided, jquery is client sided.

Comment: You can "call" JS functions using PHP, your PHP will just output HTML / JS so you do what you want. Did you notice you miss <?php closure ?

Comment: @OleKristianAanensen I disagree, the OP wants to `echo/print` a line of `<script>` based on a PHP `if` statement it should be possible, HTML output

Comment: @EruPenkman he wants to do the other way around. PHP -> jquery, not a ajax request.

Comment: @AdamAzad yes, that's why I commented "You cannot call jquery functions **directly** from PHP."

Comment: @VincentDecaux - I not miss <?php ?>. How can I do this?

Comment: @VincentDecaux - can you tell me how I should correct my code to do what I want? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is JavaScript scoping: the function you're trying to call is not accessible from everywhere.

```
$(function() {
    function reset_fields(){
        // this function is only accessible to things inside $(function(){...
    }
}
```

That means that you can't access it directly. However, if you place the function outside, it will work:

```
function reset_fields() {
    // now this function is globally accessible from anywhere
}

$(function() {
    // you can still call reset_fields() from here
}
```

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO!! THANK U VERY MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

Php runs on the server and javascript on the client, so the terminology "call a javascript function" [is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722747/call-jquery-function-from-php).

You can set a javascript variable with php then test that variable with javascript on the client. This will [make your code a bit simpler](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript)

```
 var postId = '<?php echo $_POST["id"] ?>';

 if( postId === '1'){
  reset_field();
 }
 else {
  reset_field();
 }
```

Comment: You missed "echo" before $_POST['id'];

Comment: thank you but I want to do it by php..