# How do I call a php function with a jquery ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using jquery $.ajax to call a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function)

I need to call a specific php function within my php file. Is there any way to point to that function with jquery ajax call instead of calling the whole URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a PHP framework, here are some ways to do it:

1 - Put the function in its own file.

2 - Put a wrapper function in its own file: all it does is #require your file, then call your desired function.

3 - Create one file that handles ajax (that'll be the entry point). Then pass a choice of functions using GET. Something like ajax_handler.php?fn=MyFunction

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You may need to factor out the function. Place it in a separate file and have it `echo` a JSON response or whatever you see fit when it is being called via Ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can try if the following StackOverflow question answers your query:

[jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

[using jquery $.ajax to call a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function)

Also, some more information on what exactly and why do you wish to get such a functionality might be useful.