# How can i print a report in Javascript while processing PHP script?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session

I am trying to print a report in a textArea using Javascript or JQuery as i want to show user what is happening while a PHP script is processing in background for some time, so the user won't think the application hanged.

So i tried to automatically update the textArea using setTimeout(...), and set the report value in the session through the PHP script while it is processing to get that variable in the client side and print it in the textArea.

*Here is the code i used :*

```
/*
 * The client side javascript function that updates the textArea value.
 */
function updateReport() {
    var reportValue = '<?php echo( $_SESSION[ 'report' ] ); ?>';
    document.forms[ 'start_send_form' ].elements[ 'reportTextArea' ].value = reportValue;

    setTimeout(function () {
        updateReport();
    }, 500);
}
```

The php script that is called by the client side through an Ajax(JQuery) request :

```
<?php
    $report = "";

    for( $i = 0; $i < $number_of_items_to_process; $i++ ) {
        $report .= "- Processing a new item";
        $_SESSION[ 'report' ] = $report;    
        // .... Process some long code here.
    }
?>
```

But it seems that updateReport() executes just once when it is first called, then resumes when the PHP script is done.

**Can you explain this for me ?**

**And is there a way to accomplish what i want ?**

---------------------------------- >> **Update: The code i use trying to get the updated value for $_SESSION[ 'report' ] from server side :**

```
// 1. JavaScript :
function updateReport() {
    $.ajax({  
          url: "test2.php",  
          type: "POST",  
          cache: false,  
          success: function( returned_value ){
                var reportValue = $.trim( returned_value );
                alert(reportValue);  // All messages appear after PHP script ends.
          }
    });  

    setTimeout(function () {
        updateReport();
    }, 500);
}

// 2. test2.php(Script just made to get $_SESSION[ 'report' ]) :
<?php
    if ( !isset( $_SESSION ) ) session_start();
    echo( $_SESSION[ 'report' ] );
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

When your visit a php site for example test.php it gets translated from the server to html and gets send to your webbrowser.

So:

```
function updateReport() {
    var reportValue = '<?php echo( $_SESSION[ 'report' ] ); ?>';
    document.forms[ 'start_send_form' ].elements[ 'reportTextArea' ].value = reportValue;

    setTimeout(function () {
        updateReport();
    }, 500);
}
```

Will be in the webbrowser (you can look this up in the firebug or chrome dev tool):

```
function updateReport() {
    var reportValue = '';
    document.forms[ 'start_send_form' ].elements[ 'reportTextArea' ].value = reportValue;

    setTimeout(function () {
        updateReport();
    }, 500);
}
```

Because $_SESSION['report'] is empty when you visit the site.

When you do your ajax request, you call code on the server. When you set $_SESSION['report'] it is set on the server. But the client doesn't get that information because the client (your webbrowser) doesn't know what PHP is. It just sets an empty string over and over again, because it only got the generated html (from the PHP file) AT THE PAGE REQUEST.

You have to make an extra Ajax request to get the new value from the $_SESSION['report'] to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I agree with you, but when i get the $_SESSION['report'] through an Ajax request from server it grabs it after the PHP script is done ! When i do an alert for the returned value all the alert messages appear at once after the PHP script ends processing.

Comment: You have to write an extra PHP method which just returns the $SESSION['report'] and call it. Then it gives you the current state of the report variable. Here you can see how you can call a specific PHP method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function You just have to write an action/method getReport and whatYouWannaDo. Then start the whatYouWannaDo Ajax request and call all x seconds the getReport PHP method via ajax till whatYouWannaDo is done.

Comment: But in the alerts, the correct reports are displayed? 
Can you please add your new code via edit into your post and write a short description what you did. thx.

Comment: Your code looks right to me... Are you trying it in IE? (A college once had a problem with ajax and IE.) In case you are, can you try it in FF or Chrome... But thats just my last idea, because I can't figure out why its not working... sorry :(

Comment: I am actually using Chrome. Is there a single and multi-threading in PHP for variables ? What i mean if script1 is already accessing a variable, then script2 can't access it unless script1 ends its work.

Comment: I don't know PHP that well... But something like that could be. That the session is blocked If a other PHP Script already started it. 
Try this by chaning test2.php to echo "Hello world". Comes the alert still at the end?

Answer (score 1):

While you could use [HTTP Streaming](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming) to do this, i would choose a bit different way to solve this issue.

Since processing of all the items will take time, it should be done by a background process. In PHP you can do this with [`pcntl_fork()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php).

First, you have to start the processing:

1. check if file `foobar.pid` exists
2. if file is not there, create it, otherwise - *goto **9***
3. pick next item from queue
4. process the item
5. if `foobar.pid` contains "kill", then *goto **8***
6. if queue is empty: *goto **8***
7. *goto **3***
8. delete file `foobar.pid`
9. end

This would cause the the background process to check, there already exist one such process. Also it would enable you to stop the loop, by putting "kill" inside the file.

So .. what about the reporting? As part of processing, you should have the background service to write status messages to some `status.txt` file.

This file then can be read by your XHR (what marketing people call - AJAX) script. And the same JavaScript code can check, if processing of all items has been done (because the `foobar.pid` file is gone).

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this:

1. http://www.silverspider.com/2005/php-progress-bar/
2. http://www.redips.net/javascript/ajax-progress-bar/ - this one has a functional demo where You can see the progress bar loads...