# How can I take jquery id in session

Tags: php, jquery

This is my jQuery code for taking id value when I click `itemslist`

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('.itemslist ul li').click(function()
    { $id = $(this).attr("class"); 
   }); 
});
```

But session is not taking that id value

```
session_start(); 

$_SESSION['catname'] = $id;

$id= $_SESSION['catname']; 

session_destroy();
```

Can any one please say the answer about this?

Answer (score 5):

You can't assign values to PHP variables from withing Javascript/Jquery. You should make an AJAX call to a PHP file that handles the creation/destroying of the SESSION.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function) answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax for send your id to server page and store your id in session.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {    
$('.itemslist ul li').click(function()
        { id = $(this).attr("class"); 
$.ajax({
        type   : "POST",
        url    : Postpage.php,
        data   :"id="+id ,
        success: function (json) {
            alert(json); 
          }

});  
});
```

Server side

```
session_start(); 
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$_SESSION['catname'] = $id;

$id= $_SESSION['catname']; 

session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

for that you need to call the `Ajax` to store the session value, given example code here

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('.itemslist ul li').click(function()  { 

  var id = $(this).attr("class");
    $.ajax({
                type   : "POST",
                url    : youphppage.php,
                data   :"id="+id ,
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg); // you will get stored session value here       
                  }
      });
   });
 });
```

In your php page while ajax call,

```
session_start(); 

$_SESSION['catname'] = $_POST['id'];;

echo $id= $_SESSION['catname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery ajax to send the data in a php file in post method and retrieve the value on that page

```
   $(document).ready(function() { 
      $('.itemslist ul li').click(function()
        { var a = $(this).attr("class");
          var dataString = 'a=' + a; 
        $.ajax(function(){
          type : "POST",
          url  : "session.php",
          data : dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
              alert('session sent!');
         }
       });
  });
```

});

and the session.php:

```
session_start(); 

$a= issest($_POST['a']):$_POST['a']:"";

$_SESSION['catname'] = $a; 

session_destroy();
```