# Check a submitted value using Ajax jQuery and return another value

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hello I am a beginner and need some guidance on how to achieve this using jQuery

I want to post one text field value using Ajax to a PHP script that will take this value and check it against a database query. If the value exists I want the query to also retrieve other matching row data.

This data should then be sent back to the Ajax script.I then need to access this data so I can manipulate it using jQuery.

Can anyone give me a an idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jQuery's AJAX function

```
 var request = $.ajax({
     url: "yourscript.php",
     data: {

     }
 });

 request.done(function(data){

 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, This is what I have so far: I am using this in Wordpress

`jQuery("#ajaxquery").live( "submit" , function(){
    var formdata = jQuery(this).serialize();
    jQuery.post( "login_new.php", formdata, function( data ) {
        jQuery("#my").html ( data );
    });

    return false; 
});`