# Execute Link without page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using jquery $.ajax to call a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function)

I have a couple of links (all different) that I want to execute without linking anywhere. Unlike other questions I don't want to send any data using a form, nor do I want to like to the same page everytime the link is clicked, I simply want to run the php script associated with the link but stay on the page the user is currently on. Ajax? jQuery?

Comment: Many examples/tutorials available: https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+examples

Answer (score 3):

```
<a class="ajaxLink" href="myScript.php">Ajaxed link</a>
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

```
$('.ajaxLink').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevents default link action
  $.ajax({
     url: $(this).attr('href'),
     success: function(data){
       // Do something
     }
  });
});
```

The default method for jQuery ajax is GET, but you can change this. Read about the options available at the above link.

Comment: thanks, but there will be several links on one page, so wouldn't using class cause 'confusion' between the links?

Comment: It would separate your ajax'd links from your normal links... The result of which is clarity, not confusion...