# Javascript method to trigger function on another php page to update MySQL

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php page that uses `onclick` in the rectangular coordinates of the area of a map.

When the user clicks in this area I need a function on another php page to update MySQL for that user_id

**page_1.php** - user is logged in as user_id

```
<map id="map_id_01" name="map_name_01">
<area shape="poly" id="area_id_01" class="" title="area_title_01" 
onclick="page_2.php myfunction" 
coords="360,236,696,236,696,448,360,448,360,237"/></map>
```

**page_2.php**

```
<?php myfunction($user_id); ?>
```

What JavaScript method would work on **page_1.php** to trigger the function on **page_2.php**

Comment: sounds like a job for AJAX

Comment: What would the AJAX code look like

Comment: A click and 35 keystrokes to ask that. You could have saved 30 by typing ajax into the address bar of a modern web browser and hitting return. Good devs are lazy. Never forget that.

Comment: Thanks for your help... 35-30 though = 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming jquery, and a very basic example

```
function addMap(userid)
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://domain.com/page_2.php",
       data: "userid="+userid,
       success: function(msg){
         alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); //Anything you want
       }
     });
}
```

page_2.php

```
if(!empty($_POST['userid'])){
myfunction($_POST['userid']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just call a PHP function directly from a page. You see, the `onclick` property and other similar ones such as `onblur` call a **JavaScript** function! In order to call a function from another PHP page, what you need is to use AJAX.

Here, this question should be enough for you (and it seems to be a duplicate aswell): [using jquery $.ajax to call a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function)

However, make sure you're using jQuery for this one, but if you aren't, you can replace it with plain old AJAX like this:

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", 'page_2.php', true);
xmlhttp.send('test');
//xmlhttp.responseText will return the response as a text, and xmlhttp.responseXML will return it as xml
```