# Mysql Delete row in form>table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Can you ajax post a single input from a form with a seperate form ajax function than the forms submit? I am trying to delete a table row within a form, without submitting the entire form.

Comment: I used  $.post( 
     'delete_use.php',
     {number_use:"<?=$uses_row['number_use']?>"},
     function( data ){  

    }); and it works well combined with my jquery below..... Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

particular Row hide from table... Display wise that row is removed..

```
$("#row"+i).animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 1000 });
```

Next ajax function calls for deletion..

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the row in jQuery and call remove on its object.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ERw4/)**

```
$('#rowId').remove();
```

You can use jQuery ajax to call php function with javascript, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function) shows how to do it.

Comment: $(document).on("click","#delete_this_row<?php echo $poop?>", function(){
  var answer = confirm("Are you sure you would like to delete this use");
  if(answer === true){
  $(this).closest("table.appended_use").remove();
  }
  else
  {
   
  }
  
  return false;
 });

Comment: that is my jquery and it works fine but i would like to send an ajax post to a php helper script to delete it from mysql

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can send `ajax post request` via jquery.

Guidance code is as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('.delete_link').click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var main_selector = $(this);


        $.ajax({

            url        : href,
            type       : 'post',
            dataType   : 'json',
            beforeSend : function()
            {
                //code before ajax send
            },
            success    : function(response)
            {
                if(response)
                {
                    main_selector.parent().remove();
                }
            }

        });

    });

});

</script>


<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Data1</td>
        <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>>" class="delete_link"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data2</td>
        <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>>" class="delete_link"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data3</td>
        <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>>" class="delete_link"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```