# simple jquery.ajax returns undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, undefined

I know these are everywhere but I can't seem to see the error in my code. I'm making a simple ajax call with datatype json. This call seems to succeed but does not return anything and the alert prints `undefined`.

javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if(jQuery('#statesel').length) {
        var dataString;

        dataString = "nonce=" + dynoselect.post_dyno_select_nonce;
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: dynoselect.ajaxurl,
            dataType: "json",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result.status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

php:

```
<?php
add_action("init", "ci_enqueuer");
add_action("wp_ajax_dyno_select", "dyno_select");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_dyno_select", "dyno_select");

function ci_enqueuer() {
    wp_register_script('dyno_select_script', plugins_url('/js/dyno_select_script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('dyno_select_script', 'dynoselect', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 'post_dyno_select_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('dyno_select_nonce')));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('dyno_select_script');
}

function dyno_select() {
    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];

    //checking token, looking for funny business
    if (!wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'dyno_select_nonce')) {
        $result['status'] = 'nonce failed';
        $result = json_encode($result);
        echo $result;
        die();
    }

    $result['status'] = 'success';
    echo json_encode($result);
    die();
}
?>
```

Just as a note this is being done with Wordpress, hence the `init` function. Thought I would keep that in for good measure.

Comment: You might need to set the `Content-type` header in your PHP: `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Comment: I would suggest that you open up the chrome inspector (`ctrl + i` or `Mac + i`) and go to the network tab. Then view the XHR requests and you can inspect that return result for your AJAX call. Are you actually getting data back? You define a couple of funciton, but I don't see any code that is actually being executed (unless it's in the `init`).

Comment: hall.stephenk: I added the content-type to the front of the dyno_select funtion in the php, no change there. John: I went to "Network" in the Inspector. There is an admin-ajax.php with all sorts of info but it does say status: OK and the Response sub tab shows: 0. Im not sure what to look at in these tabs for sure.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.ajax` has 3 arguments for `success` callback. First one is a data with your specified type (JSON in your example). So it has no status property.

In addition, when you get alert on success, It means that `Content-type` has been set correctly and is a valid JSON object.

Try using :

```
success: function(result, status, XHR) {
     alert(XHR.status);
}
```

Comment: Omid: Recieved 200 status back.

Comment: @deadpickle So what do you expected ?

Comment: I guess I expect result to contain data from the ajax call, and it doesnt. Not entirely sure what 200 means but Inspector shows admin-ajax.php as ok.

Answer (score 0):

That JSON parameter string doesn't look like it will work.  Is the call posting to the server correctly?

If it is, ignore this.

If not, I suggest including json2.js (http://www.json.org/js.html) and stringify-ing your data parameter before calling jQuery.ajax:

```
var jsonData = { param1: 'something', param2: 999 };
var dataString = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

**EDIT:**
the example in this accepted [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2269397/249153) doesn't stringify, but it does construct and pass a valid JSON object.  And shows the server side parsing.

Comment: I gave your stringify example an attempt but I still get undefined returned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the POST did not pass "action" along with the ajax call. As soon as "action" was added to the url, everything worked.