# Sending data with AJAX to a PHP file and using that data to run a PHP script

Tags: php, ajax, forms, validation

I'm currently trying to make live form validation with PHP and AJAX. So basically - I need to send the value of a field through AJAX to a PHP script(I can do that) and then I need to run a function inside that PHP file with the data I sent. How can I do that?

JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'validate.php',
  data: 'user=' + t.value,   //(t.value = this.value),
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    someId.html(data);
  }
});
```

Validate.php:

// Now I need to use the "user" value I sent in this function, how can I do this?

```
function check_user($user) {
  //process the data
}
```

If I don't use functions and just raw php in validate.php the data gets sent and the code inside it executed and everything works as I like, but if I add every feature I want things get very messy so I prefer using separate functions.

I removed a lot of code that was not relevant to make it short.

Comment: you can get data in $_POST and than call that function whats problem ?

Comment: You could pass in a post data value of 'function=check_user' and then in the php code use a switchcase command pattern to execute accordingly, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function for more deats...

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/q/5004233/1723893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to call the function inside your file.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['user'])){
    check_user($_REQUEST['user']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. With some more tinkering I managed to get things working by calling the function at the top of my PHP, but this is much better!

Comment: I did not include this in my answer - but please take care to sanitize ANY input you receive via GET, POST etc.! If you don't this will open doors wide for XSS and SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

1) This doesn't look nice

```
data: 'user=' + t.value,   //(t.value = this.value),
```

This is nice

```
data: {user: t.value},
```

2) Use $_POST

```
function check_user($user) {
    //process the data
}
check_user($_POST['user'])
```

Comment: Yes, I read that previously today, but why exactly is the `{user: t.value}` better?

Comment: It is easier to read and it is syntax of official documentation. So I suppose you better hold to this syntax if you don't want to get in trouble now and later.

Answer (score 1):

In your validate.php you will receive classic POST request. You can easily call the function depending on which variable you are testing, like this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['user'])) {
    $result = check_user($_POST['user']);
}
elseif (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $result = check_email($_POST['email']);
}
elseif (...) {
    // ...
}

// returning validation result as JSON
echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
exit();

function check_user($user) {
   //process the data
   return true; // or flase
}

function check_email($email) {
   //process the data
   return true; // or false
}

// ...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is send in the `$_POST` global variable. You can access it when calling the check_user function:

```
check_user($_POST['user']);
```

If you do this however remember to check the field value, whether no mallicious content has been sent inside it.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I do it

**Jquery Request**

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "ajax/transferstation-lookup.php",
            data: {
                'supplier': $("select#usedsupplier").val(),
                'csl': $("#csl").val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                if (data["queryresult"]==true) {
                    //add returned html to page
                    $("#destinationtd").html(data["returnedhtml"]);
                } else {
                    jAlert('No waste destinations found for this supplier please select a different supplier', 'NO WASTE DESTINATIONS FOR SUPPLIER', function(result){ return false; });
                }
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

**PHP Page**
Just takes the 2 input

```
$supplier = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->mysqli,$_POST["supplier"]);
$clientservicelevel = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->mysqli,$_POST["csl"]);
```

Runs them through a query.  Now in my case I just return raw html stored inside a json array with a check flag saying query has been successful or failed like this

```
$messages = array("queryresult"=>true,"returnedhtml"=>$html);
echo json_encode($messages); //encode and send message back to javascript
```

If you look back at my initial javascript you'll see I have conditionals on queryresult and then just spit out the raw html back into a div you can do whatever you need with it though.