# how to call function in php file from the external js file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook

I have to call below function call to my php file...if any one have idea please help....

```
  function update_hidden_input(saved_tokens, hidden_input) 
{
    var token_values = $.map(saved_tokens, function (el) 
{
            //alert(el[settings.tokenValue]);
            return el[settings.tokenValue];
 });

    hidden_input.val(token_values.join(settings.tokenDelimiter));
         //var frienduid =(token_values.join(settings.tokenDelimiter));
        //alert(frienduid);
    }
```

Comment: Please search before asking, this has been asked and answered many times. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688946/sending-data-with-ajax-to-a-php-file-and-using-that-data-to-run-a-php-script

Comment: @ChristophGrimmer-Dietrich i don't know how it call because it gives me call to undefined function error.....

Comment: @ChristophGrimmer-Dietrich i include the script where this function was reside..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can done with it by using `jQuery.ajax()` or `jQuery.post()` function to send data to the **PHP**. but it is not secured. Because JavaScript is open for all browser. Bad guys can send unexpected data and take chances to harm your app / web. Anyway it is your choice.

Check [facebook server-side-login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/), it can help you more.