# PHP RadioButton Submit form

Tags: php, post, radio-button, submit

I have been creating a website to allow users to rate an image uploaded by another user. I have my code working great. The user is presented with the image, a button to flag the image, 10 radio buttons to choose their rating and a submit button (all within the same form).

My problem is that I would like to remove the submit button and process the form when the user clicks the radio button. The problem with this is that the flag button (image button) is also submitting the form. My code is below:

**HTML**

```
<form name="ratebox" action="Box.php?bid=<?php echo $boxId ?>" method="post">
    <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><img src="img/boxes/<?php echo $boxId ?>.png" title="<?php echo $boxName ?>" height="350" width="350"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
    <input
        type="image"
        name="flag_submit"
        src="img/Flag.png"
        onmouseover="this.src='img/Flag_Click.png'"
        onmouseout="this.src='img/Flag.png'"
        height="30"
        width="30"
        />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">
            1<input type="radio" name="rdoRate" value="1" >
            2<input type="radio" name="rdoRate" value="2" >
            3<input type="radio" name="rdoRate" value="3" >
            4<input type="radio" name="rdoRate" value="4" >
            5<input type="radio" name="rdoRate" value="5" >
            6<input type="radio" name="rdoRate" value="6" >
            7<input type="radio" name="rdoRate" value="7" >
            8<input type="radio" name="rdoRate" value="8" >
            9<input type="radio" name="rdoRate" value="9" >
            10<input type="radio" name="rdoRate" value="10" > 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan='4' align='center'><input type='submit' name='rate_submit' value='Rate'></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['flag_submit_x']))
{
        //Code to process the flagged image
}

if (!empty($_POST['rate_submit']))
{
        //Code to process the rated image
}
```

Is there any way I can submit the form when a radio button is pressed and retrieve the value of the radio button that has been pressed?

Comment: In html you need a button to send data. You need to use js for this

Comment: I am using PHP along side HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use Javascript for that. Using jQuery,

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
     return false;
});

$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    $('form').submit();
});
```

You need to learn how to use $.ajax() to transfer info to and from PHP. [Read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function)

Comment: How would I process and retrieve the values being sent in the PHP code?

Comment: I have tried this method out and i am unable to get it working. Would you be able to provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is, why no attach a js function to each button and have it send the value to the server either ajax or regular.

```
function submitRate(image_id, rating){
//here you would do the magic:)
//maybe grab other form fields or just the rating
}
```

and in your buttons `onclick="submitRate()"`

Comment: How would I send the information from js to PHP and how would I process and retrieve the values in PHP?

Comment: in your submitRate() send an ajax call to a back end php script and return the result

Answer (score 0):

1) remove the submit input.

2) make the form submit false:

```
<form id="ratebox" name="ratebox" action="" method="" onSubmit="return false;">
```

3)Put post code to the submit page:

```
$.post("Box.php?bid=<?php echo $boxId ?>", $("#ratebox").serialize());
```

Comment: This would not work as I am using an image button (flagged button) within the same form to submit a request.