# Values from Javascript into PHP Variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two Javascript functions that will return values.
I have little experience in JS and PHP, so what I was wondering - is how would I append the variables to a hidden field, and get them with PHP so I can perform some arithmetic with it, and return a final value which I can then display.

I can do the last part (calculate the last value, and display it).
I was wondering how I could post the variables from the JS function, and get them with PHP saving them to a PHP variable **WITHOUT USER INTERACTION** - This is the most important part, it needs to be done automatically.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You're looking for AJAX.

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function another good one, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/

Comment: Great. AJAX, I've been using it for other functions in my code. But my question persists, how would I pass a value in JS to a PHP Variable?

Comment: Safixk, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to do this is to use AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript and XML).

### JavaScript

```
$.post("/myfile.php", {phpvariable: javascriptvariable}, function(data) {
   // Do something after successfully sent.
   // e.g. location.reload();
 });
```

This will send you a POST variable without any user interaction to the specified PHP file.

### myfile.php

```
<?php
   $javascriptvariable = $_POST['phpvariable'];
?>
```

Comment: Trying this out now. Thanks.

Comment: Safixk: Let me know if it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to this.

You can insert the value into the query string and reload the page.

```
function send_to_php(var value) {
    window.location.assign("mypage.php?value=" + value);
}
```

In PHP, this is then stored in `$_GET['value']` and `$_REQUEST['value']`.

You can also put the value inside a hidden input field in a form and run

```
document.getElementById('my_form').submit()
```

If you do not want the page to reload, you should use AJAX: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

EDIT:

To run functions in JavaScript without use interaction, just call the function anywhere inside a script, like `send_to_php(44);`. You can also use `setTimeout("send_to_php(44)", 10000)` to wait 10 seconds before calling the function.

If you wish the function to be run several times, call `setTimeout` again at the end of the function.