# How do i run a sql query in my facebook fan page to my Html Form

Tags: php, html, mysql, facebook

Well,

I've a Facebook Fan Page where a html form is showing using Static Html : Iframe tabs.

I just put my all html, css, javascript code using the iframe tab. But this form require category value from my website database. But You know this iframe is not support php or even Facebook. (not sure).

So is there any way to get my database table value to my html form in Facebook Fan page ?

**Facebook fan page link** :

https://www.facebook.com/pages/My-food/596766723726381?id=596766723726381&sk=app_190322544333196

Update:

```
    <script>
    function showHint(str)
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str.length==0)
      { 
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","formulairefb.gastronoome.com/get_data.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>

<h3>Start typing a name in the input field below:</h3>
<form action=""> 
First name: 
<input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" />
</form>
```

Suggestions:

(suggestion will be show here)

Php page:

```
    <?php
    // Fill up array with names
    $a[]="Anna";
    $a[]="Brittany";
    $a[]="Cinderella";
    $a[]="Diana";
    $a[]="Eva";
    $a[]="Fiona";
    $a[]="Gunda";
    $a[]="Hege";
    $a[]="Inga";
    $a[]="Johanna";
    $a[]="Kitty";
    $a[]="Linda";
    $a[]="Nina";
    $a[]="Ophelia";
    $a[]="Petunia";
    $a[]="Amanda";
    $a[]="Raquel";
    $a[]="Cindy";
    $a[]="Doris";
    $a[]="Eve";
    $a[]="Evita";
    $a[]="Sunniva";
    $a[]="Tove";
    $a[]="Unni";
    $a[]="Violet";
    $a[]="Liza";
    $a[]="Elizabeth";
    $a[]="Ellen";
    $a[]="Wenche";
    $a[]="Vicky";

    // get the q parameter from URL
    $q=$_REQUEST["q"]; $hint="";

    // lookup all hints from array if $q is different from ""
    if ($q !== "")
      { $q=strtolower($q); $len=strlen($q);
        foreach($a as $name)
        { if (stristr($q, substr($name,0,$len)))
          { if ($hint==="")
            { $hint=$name; }
            else
            { $hint .= ", $name"; }
          }
        }
      }

    // Output "no suggestion" if no hint were found
    // or output the correct values
    echo $hint==="" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
    ?>
```

Comment: You would need to use `AJAX`.

Comment: @dollarvar can you please give me an example ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function. ;) I would suggest you use jQuery for that, makes life easier for Ajax calls.

Comment: @dollarvar let me check it.

Comment: @dollarvar check my update questions. This a name suggestion form. It's working on my localhost. But It's not working in my facebook page. Do you know why ?

Comment: Either there is something wrong on facebook form or you did not upload it correctly, however I cannot spot mistakes on code copied from w3schools.com. ;)