# check username availability with ajax in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, controller

I am using this function to check the username availability type function in laravel framework-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#clanname").keyup(function(e) {

        var clanname = $(this).val();
        if(clanname.length < 4){$("#user-result").html('');return;}

        if (clanname.length >= 4) {
            $("#user-result").html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.post('/Myclan/checkClanname', {'clanname':clanname}, function(data) {
               console.log(data);
            });
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

which calls the controller Myclan/checkClanname -

```
public function checkClanname() {
        $clanCount = Clan::where('clanname', '=', Input::get('clanname'))->count();
        if ($clanCount == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

but I am getting an error popup

Comment: `Boolean` is not proper html content. Try returning text like "Free"/"Taken" and check. If you want to pass data structures use `JSON`.

Comment: This may help when you want to call a php function using ajax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function

Comment: still getting the same error apopup with message 'object not found' .

Comment: Why is this tagged Laravel and your url is `/Myclan/checkClanname.php`? Seems like a plain and simple PHP file, not Laravel. Is your javascript being able to find this script? Try to use the full url to check.

Comment: sorry It was /Myclan/checkClanname where 'Myclan' is the controllername and 'checkClanname' is the action or function inside that controller

Comment: Can you post the relevant routes for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$clanCount = Clan::where('clanname', '=', Input::get('clanname'))->get()->count();
```