# Call a php method from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I use this simple javascript code to call a php function from javascript.

```
var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
        a.open("GET","save.php");
        a.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( a.readyState == 4) {
            if( a.status == 200) {
                alert("Worked");
            }
        else alert("HTTP error "+a.status+" "+a.statusText);
        }
        }
        a.send();
```

In this example I have a php function `save()` contained into `save.php` file.
I have some questions:

1) How can I call a php function that it is located into the same file where there is the javascript function? (I would to call a php method declared into the same file where there is the javascript caller)

2) Is possible to pass also an php array as parameter?

Comment: You can't call PHP function directly with ajax, you can only get the output of the file and pass GET or POST data to that file. That means you can send data that tells the file to do certain things, and that's as close as you'll get.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that, since php is executed and evaluated on the server and javascript is executed in browser... so javascript on the client side does not know anything about that php code

Comment: send some id and value along with the save.php and check if that variable is exists in php and call the function and return whatever you want

Comment: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function

Maybe this link could help. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use ajax call as described manner--

**On javascript side on save.php page-**

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:'demodata',                                                      
        url:"save.php?action=php_function",  // place your php function name here
        dataType: "html",
    success:function(response){
            alert(response);       // It will alert value returned by php function
    },

    failure:function(response){
            alert("there is an error.");
    },

});
```

**On PHP side on save.php page-**

```
<?php

  if(function_exists($_GET['action'])) 
  { 
     $_GET['action'](); 
  }
  else
  {
        echo 'There is some error.';
  }

  function php_function()
  {
     // some code
     echo "result";
  }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First: You are not "calling a function". You are making a request to a server. The request is "interpreted" in php, and php has a function defined that is called. Js never calls php directly (one is front side, one is back).

To answer your questions:

1. You need to make the request to the same page you are displaying, but your js will also be executed.
2. Yes, but I suggest a post not a get for this (use var_name[] for array, where var_name is the name of the array).

As side notes:
Having both php and js in the same file is usually a bad idea. Try to isolate the front-end from the back-end as much as possible (it may be hard at first, but it will save you from huuuge headaches).

The script you are using is fine for simple things, but lacks lots of things (what if destination was moved and you get a redirect state, what if is unreachable, what if you need a callback, etc.). You are also limited at GET, and for some thing you may prefer POST method. I suggest using js lib for your requests (like jQuery ajax, prototype ajax, etc.) that take care of this things. Or you can extend your script of course.

Answer (score 0):

In general, passing an array between PHP and Javascript is better done using a JSON document as interchange format.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to detect the request was made via ajax so that you can run the `save()` function, or if not then output the page normally, with the JavaScript caller included.

There are a number of ways to detect ajax, one would be to set the `X-Requested-With` header, which you can check on the PHP side.

save.php

```
function save(){
    // some PHP code here
}

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'){
    // request was made via ajax, call the function
    save();
    exit(); // exit so no page content is sent via ajax
}

// output the page content including JavaScript caller
```

JavaScript:

```
var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
a.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest'); // set the header
// continue with your XHR code
```

The best way to send an array would be to JSON encode it before sending via POST, then JSON decode on the PHP side.

JavaScript:

```
a.open("POST","save.php");
a.send('json=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.encode(myArray)));
```

PHP

```
function save(){
    $myArray = json_decode($_POST['json']);
}
```