# Call a simple PHP function with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function

How can i call a php function with a query inside on ajax?

My html:

```
<input type="submit" value="Open Process" name="openProcess" id="openProcess" onclick="javascript:applicationOpenProcess()" >
```

And my php function:

```
function openProcess(){
    $id = $_GET['application']; //Nodata need where is coming from the URL
    $openProcess = "UPDATE applications SET  process='1' WHERE application_id='".$id."'";
    $valProcess = db_query($openProcess, "+"); //function to execute query
}
```

Guys i really need help on this one
Thanks mates

Comment: We also need help of you to know what have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [using jquery $.ajax to call a PHP function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this other answer:
[jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

as lampdev wrote above, you'll just need to adapt the basic aJax call to your code

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:"code.php",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function () { }
});
```

The other answer will help you doing what you want, and it's great for ajax beginners

You'll need 3 files, supposing you've js in a different file as the form. It will be something like:

- form.php/html
- script.js
- code.php

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is take a look at the Ajax documentation:https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Ajax is for sending requests but it is possible to get something to run on the success:

Here is a basic Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax_content.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: ({
        page: page,
        content: content
    }),
    success: function (data) {  alert (data) }
 });
```

As you can see the function in success passes back 'data'. so, lets say you wanted to pass back some information you had got from a database. you would need to make sure that the output is json_encode($data); in the ajax_content.php page. That would then give you something. You can then use alert() to see the data. Make sense?

Comment: page:page and content:content are declared variables that allow you pass info to the file. Like if you needed to pass a password or id etc..

Answer (score 0):

By ajax you can only send request. You may send it to the page that calls your function as you need

Answer (score 0):

what you need to is create a php file write your code and simply call that php file via ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:"example.php",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function () { }
});
```