# Javascript variable passed to PHP session in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, session

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I have a button that when pressed it call a `onClick` JS function and it passed two parameters. I want to save those two parameters on a php session, then load another page and use those values.

So, I know that if I use something like this on PAGE !:

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $message1 = "A message";
    $message2 = "Another message";

    $_SESSION['routineName'] = $message1;
    $_SESSION['dayName'] = $message2; 
    ?>
```

I can go to PAGE 2, and by using `$_SESSION['routineName']` I can use that info.

So, on PAGE 1 I have that code inside the function that is called with my `onClick`:

```
function trackIt(routine, dayName) 
{
    <?php
    session_start();

    $message1 = "A message";
    $message2 = "Another message";

    $_SESSION['routineName'] = $message1;
    $_SESSION['dayName'] = $message2; 
    ?>
}
```

I tried things like:

```
function trackIt(routine, dayName) 
{
    <?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['routineName'] = ?> routine; <?php
    $_SESSION['dayName'] = $message2; 
    ?>
}
```

and others, but nothing works.

And this is how I am calling the onClick (trackIt) function:

```
echo('<td colspan="3" style="background-color:#005673; text-align:right; padding: 4px 0px;">
<button class="btnTrack" onClick="trackIt(\'' . $name . '\' , \'' . $nameday1 . '\')" >Track It!</button></td>');
```

What I want to do is to save both, routine and dayName, into the session.

Is it possible to save JS variables/parameters into PHP Session?

**PS: I am using Wordpress.**

Thanks!

Comment: That's an empty Javascript function (does nothing and returns `undefined`), since the PHP code inside it doesn't output anything.

Comment: AJAX is probably your best bet.  Here is a jQuery/AJAX example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function

Comment: But since you want to take the user to another page anyway, a form with hidden fields could work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PHP code you put in your files is **not** executed at Javascript run time, it is executed even before the page gets sent to the client. So you can't access `$_SESSION` from anywhere within your *content*, you need to do that from Wordpress's *code*. Usually this is done via [a plugin](https://managewp.com/wordpress-custom-code).

You need to pass your Javascript variables to a *server side PHP*. As @Grasshopper said, the best (or at least most maintainable way) is through AJAX:

```
// This is your JAVASCRIPT trackit function
function trackIt(routine, day) {
    $.post(
         '/wp-setvar.php',
         {
             routine  : routine,
             day      : day
         }, // You can add as many variables as you want (well, within reason)
         function success(data) {
             // Here we should receive, given the code below, an object
             // such that data.result is a string saying "OK".
             // Just in case you need to get back something from the server PHP.
             // Otherwise just leave this function out.
         }
    );
};
```

On the server, you need to **create** a specific file to accept the incoming variables (it would be best if you did this from a plugin, in order not to add files outside the installation: such practices are frowned upon by security scanners such as WordFence). This here below is a butcher's solution.

```
<?php /** This is wp-setvar.php */

/** Set up WordPress environment, just in case */
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );

session_id() || session_start();

nocache_headers();

// DO NOT, FOR ANY REASON, ACCESS DIRECTLY $_SESSION
// ONLY USE A VARIABLE WITHIN $_SESSION (here, "ajjx")
// OTHERWISE THIS MAY ALLOW ANYONE TO TAKE CONTROL OF YOUR INSTALLATION.
$_SESSION['ajjx'] = $_POST;

Header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf8');
die(json_encode(array(
    'result' => 'OK', // This in case you want to return something to the caller
)));
```

Now whenever you need the session-saved variable, e.g. "routine", you put

```
<?php

  ...
  $value = '';
  if (array_key_exists('ajjx', $_SESSION)) {
       if (array_key_exists('routine', $_SESSION['ajjx']) {
           $value = $_SESSION['ajjx']['routine'];
       }
  }
```

Or you can define a function in your plugin,

```
  function ajjx($varname, $default = '') {
      if (array_key_exists('ajjx', $_SESSION)) {
           if (array_key_exists($varname, $_SESSION['ajjx']) {
               return $_SESSION['ajjx'][$varname];
           }
      }
      return $default;
  }
```

Then you just:

```
  <?php print ajjx('routine', 'none!'); ?><!-- will print routine, or "none!" -->
```

or

```
  <?php print ajjx('routine'); ?><!-- will print nothing if routine isn't defined -->
```

An even more butcherful solution is to add the function definition above *within `wp-config.php` itself*. Then it will be available everywhere in Wordpress. Provided you have access to `wp-config.php`. Also, *backup wp-config first* and **use a full FTP client to do it; do not use a Wordpress plugin to edit it**, since if `wp-config` crashes, the plugin may crash too... and you'll find yourself in a *my-can-opener-is-locked-within-a-can* situation.

If you don't feel comfortable with some of the above, it's best if you do nothing. Or practice first on an expendable Wordpress installation that you can reinstall easily.