# JQuery change value by clicking

Tags: jquery

First, sorry for my bad English, I'm from Belgium. :)

So, I'm making a simple game with points. These points should finally to the database. My PHP script is ready and update the data of the user. Now the only problem is that I do not get my points in a variable. The idea is that you must click on a DIV and you deserve so points. Points must be send as a POST.

I hope you understand my problem. :s

Kind regards,
Rody

Comment: You can do that with ajax request.. Where you place those point?

Comment: You said the problem is cause you dont get point into variabe, which mean you already displayed the point

Comment: Yes, thats correct. But when I open my "view-source" it says 0 because thats the default start score.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).
Check this:
[using jquery $.ajax to call a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function)

Comment: You should flag the question as a duplicate rather than posting a link-only answer.