# how can I call a php function when value is typed in textbox?

Tags: javascript, php, google-search, completion

I want to do an auto completion using Firefox's suggestions. Is it possible to call a php function while typing a keyword ? Is there any better way to do it?

```
 public function stealSearchGoogle(){ 

    $lang  = 'fr';
    $query = 'developeur';
    $url   = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=firefox&client=firefox&hl=' . $lang . '&q=' . urlencode($query);

    $ch    = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1");
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $suggestions = json_decode($data, true);

    if ($suggestions) {
        //echo 'suggestions: ';
        foreach ($suggestions as $value) {
            return($value);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [using jquery $.ajax to call a PHP function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function)

Comment: I want the suggestions to appear while typing my keyword

Comment: Then look for jquery event `keyup`, `keypress`.

Comment: I think you are looking for AJAX.
Please follow this link: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp
You can modify the given example on this link to your problem statement.

Comment: @b0s3 `input` event is better.