# How to pass the value of javascript into a PHP variable and stored into mysql database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

How to get javascript variable value in PHP and php value stored in to database.

if my JS code like

var age = new Date().getFullYear()-getYearInteger();

This code o/p 2016-(yearofbirth). I am getting output correct in JS. How to store this **age** value in MySQL database. How to call ajax function and insert the values?

Comment: Make an `ajax` call or submit the form and hit `Insert` query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to save JS value to a PHP variable you need to make a server call.

You can easily do the vice versa like this:

```
var jsVariable = '<?= $php_variable ?>';
```

Have an ajax call, send the data to server side and store it in a variable.

Comment: Thank you for your response. i have no knowledge in ajax. can u explain in  detail?

Comment: @jeni just read your  comment, did you check ajax? you can see this example 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function

Comment: Its not not working Please anybody help me. i added the above code in javascript page . how to insert into database. how to call ajax

Answer (score 1):

Send this javascript value through form or **ajax submit** method and get this value saved in Database.

You cannot directly get `js` values in `Php`.

```
A simple example is 
var age  = new Date().getFullYear()-getYearInteger(); 
$.ajax({
      url : '/save.php',
      type : "POST",
      data : {
                age    : age,
                saveAge    : true,
             },
      success : function(data)
      {
              data = JSON.parse(data);
              if(data.status == 1)
              {
                   window.location = 'index.php/dashboard';
              }
              else
              {                                

              }
       }    
});
```

Comment: Thank you for response. i added the code but not stored in database. in save .php i added insert query but stored all age value as 0. can u explain that?

Comment: Can you please show me your code in save.php

Comment: @ Mukesh Swami  I just write insert query <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("numcalc", $con);
 
$sql="INSERT INTO expression (id, age) VALUES ('','$age')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "your data added successfully";
mysql_close($con)
?>