# use JSON api for live news

Tags: json, api

I have this Fox Sport API url :

https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=fox-sports&sortBy=top&apiKey=955acf3993df49169dfa33dce76d015f

How do i use this? I know it's based on Json. But where do i put this URL? in what format or file? Can someone please help me?

I alrady tried putting it between scripts tags in my index.php file but no results...

Thank you!

Comment: you'll need to use `ajax` to get the data.

Comment: I used this script but there is no output. How can i solve this?

<script>
$.ajax({
        url: "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-huffington-post&sortBy=top&apiKey=955acf3993df49169dfa33dce76d015f",
        type: 'GET',
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
    });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Google it ---> Php curl. Read the doc!
If you are using a framework, let us know which one

Comment: I used this script but there is no output. How can i solve this?

<script>
$.ajax({
        url: "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-huffington-post&sortBy=top&apiKey=955acf3993df49169dfa33dce76d015f",
        type: 'GET',
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
    });
</script>

Comment: Hoo finally you want to call api from js? Or from php? In your first post you was talking about php right??

Answer (score 0):

JSON is simply a useful way to send and receive strings that represent objects in JavaScript. In these days I'm working on an application that uses JSON strings to store and retrieve data, and I found a very simple way to get data from JSON strings, that is **jQuery**. This library has a `jQuery.getJSON()` method, which let you to load JSON-encoded data from the server (or locally) using a GET HTTP request. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) you can find all the details you need to use this method.

Obviously you could choose not to use any third-part library and do what you need in vanilla JavaScript, but jQuery is very useful since it helps to avoid common cross-browser issues.

In my application I store data from a JSON string in this way:

```
var placesList;
jQuery.getJSON("places.txt").done(function (data) {
  placesList = data;
});
```

that is using an external variable to store them using an anonymous function. As you can see, my URL here is `places.txt`, but you can use any valid URL you want that provide a JSON string.

Comment: I used this script but there is no output. How can i solve this?

<script>
$.ajax({
        url: "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-huffington-post&sortBy=top&apiKey=955acf3993df49169dfa33dce76d015f",
        type: 'GET',
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
    });
</script>

Comment: Using you code I'm able to see the data from the JSON string. Look at the code in your first comment: you didn't specify any `success` function, but only an `error` function. In this way, you aren't doing anything with the data from the server

Comment: can you send me an example of working code please? i'm a real noob at this :(

Comment: Sure! Let's create in the body a `<div id="test"></div>` element, where we will print our results. In the `script` tag, we use the `$.ajax()` function with these parameters: `https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-huffington-post&sortBy=top&apiKey=955acf3993df49169dfa33dce76d015f` for the `url`, `GET` for the `method` (is better that `type`), and finally the two functions, one `success : function(data) { $("#test").html(data.source); }` and the last `error : ...`. In this case, I'm printing the `source` property of the object

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this -

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=fox-sports&sortBy=top&apiKey=955acf3993df49169dfa33dce76d015f';
        $.getJSON(url).then(function(res){
            console.log(res) //{status: "ok", source: "fox-sports", sortBy: "top", articles: Array[10]}
            console.log(res['status']) //ok
            console.log(res['source']) //fox-sports
            console.log(res['sortBy']) //top
            console.log(res['articles'].length) //10
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: thnx! a lot but how doesn't show something on the screen? I placed the scripts in the header, but what in the Body? Thankyou!

Comment: create a function that actually wraps this code and then call it from an element event from body. If the solution provided served your purpose, mark it an answer.

Comment: wow  wow slow down, i'm a noob at this :) can you give me a example of the function and body ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function

Comment: this gave me more questions than answers haha. can you give me the code syntax like you did with the script so i can place it in the body? thank you very much!

Comment: See my last comment