# Call PHP function from external HTML?

Tags: php, ajax, html

There already are some entries about the topic explaining that the only way is by using **Ajax**. However, I do not find solution for this problem: I just want that, once **pressing a button in an HTML** file, **run a PHP function**.

Imagine I have two buttons `button1` `button2` so I want each of them to run `function run1()` `function run2()` of my PHP file.

How the Ajax would look like? This is what I have.

> HTML:

```
<script> // For button1
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("#button1").click(function(){
     var value = $("#button1").val();
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'myPHP.php',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: {button:value},
                  success: function(response){
                      $('#output').append(response);
                      }//end success

              }); //end ajax
          });
        });
</script>


<body>
    <form method="post" action="myPHP.php">

    <button id= "button1" type="submit" value="value1">Button One</button>
    <button id= "button2" type="submit" value="value2">Button Two</button>

    </form>
</body>
```

> PHP:

```
if($_POST['button'] == 'value1'){
  // run function1; 
}else{
  // run function2;
}
```

Comment: In php you'd have to determine which post variable (which button was clicked), then you'd run the function that way. Ajax is used to send the button value over

Comment: I thought Ajax let you specify the function you want to run on the php

Comment: did you name the other file myPhP.php, and inside do you have that code within <?php and ?> tags?

Comment: Yes, I checked the syntax and tags. I think it does not execute the script and goes directly to the PHP file

Comment: Are they separate files?, There should be 2, 1 for html and 1 for the php script

Comment: Yes, they are separated files and they are in the same path.

Answer (score 1):

Send the page the value via ajax, then use it within that page

```
$(document).ready(function(){

          $("#button1").click(function(){    // the #id you supplied to the button, id= 'button1'

     var value = $("#button1").val();  // Value of the button, value= 'button1value'

              $.ajax({
                  url: 'phppage.php', // The php page with the functions
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: {button:value},  // the name you're assigning, think how a $_GET works in URL,  .php?name=value...

                  success: function(response){
                      $('#output').append(response);
                      }//end success

              }); //end ajax
          });
        });
```

php page

```
if($_POST['button'] == 'button1value'){     / $_POST['name of input/button'] == 'value being sent through'

  // run function 1;
}else{
  // run function2;
}

?>
```

This post, first answer, also answers depending how you intend to use it:
[using jquery $.ajax to call a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function)

Comment: Does 'button1value' indicate wether has been pressed?

Comment: @Alonso  yes, in jquery   $("#button1").click(function(){ indicidates button 1, where as  $("#button2").click(function(){  would be what happens when it's button 2. Just give your buttons a value and use that in your php page

Comment: So please correct me if I am wrong: in this example **#button1** is the name of the button 1, **button1value** is the value of the button 1 and... what is the first **'button'** in the php page

Comment: #button1 is the ID of the button, you need to have it like this <button id='button1' value='button1value' />, button is the POST value, such as $_POST['button'] will come through as whatever value= ' ', in this case, button1value

Comment: Yup. Whatever you name inputs/buttons in HTML with name= ' ', is what comes through as $_POST or $_GET in PHP. So <input type='text' name='user' value='dog' /> on submit of a form, the post would be $_POST['user'] and will be 'dog'

Comment: I added some comments if you have any questions feel free to ask

Comment: I get this Notice message: **Notice:** Undefined index: button in file.php