# Use Jquery $.ajax to call a server side function on Flask

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I want to call a server side function using Ajax.

I have found a straightforward example for PHP [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function). I think the community would improve if we could include this very same example but for Python / Flask MVC framework.

This is the ajax code on the View side, called test.html:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function create () {
$.ajax({
url:"test1", //the page containing python script
type: "post", //request type,
dataType: 'json',
data: {registration: "success", name: "xyz", email: "abc@gmail.com"},
success:function(result){
console.log(result.abc);
      }
    });
   } 
</script>
```

And this would be the Python code on the Controller:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def test():
        return render_template("test.html", brand = brand)

@app.route('/test1', methods=['GET','POST'])
    def test1():
        if registration == "success":
            return json.dump({"abc":'successfuly registered'});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the arguments to the view function. Access posted data with `request.form`. Return a JSON response using `jsonify`. The view *must* return a response from each execution path.

```
@app.route('/test1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test1():
    if request.form.get('registration') == 'success':
        return jsonify({'abc': 'successfuly registered'})

    return jsonify({'abc': 'registration unsuccessful'})
```