# How to a call a php function within the same document from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I want to call a php function after an event listener within the same document. So I have PHP, HTML and all in the same file. I looked in this thread: [using jquery $.ajax to call a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function). However in the url it is a separate file.

```
document.getElementById("categoryone").addEventListener("change", function(event)
{
    $.ajax({ url: 'pageTwo.php',
      data: {action: 'test'},
      type: 'post',
      success: function(output) {
                 alert(output);
               }
    });
});
```

And my PHP looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'test' : test();break;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: it should be a separate file.  Otherwise your HTML will be output and mess up your response.  `However in the url it is a separate file.`  If it's in the same file, you will get the html from that file, anything that is output is returned in the response from the server.

Comment: Side note - as you are using jquery, why not shorten to `$("#categoryone").on("change", function(event) { ...` or `$("#categoryone").change( function(event) { ...`?

Comment: It don't work as I have it. Can you have the php in the same file? Or are you forced to have it in a seperate file? What should I put I the url to call the php function

Comment: Do you understand that PHP always runs on the server, before the page is sent to the client?  If you "call a PHP function" that call runs the full page (not just that function) *on the server* and sends the results back as a response.  Using F12 in the browser and watching the Network tab might make this more clear.