# JSON parse error - Javascript from PHP json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I tried to solve this for eight hours, no luck, so I'm begging for help. I'm a hobbyist programmer.
Short overview:
php-file reads values, creates two-dimensional array that is exported via "echo" and "json_encode". Then read by html/javascript/jquery. Then these array values should auto-populate the corresponding  fields every second.

The error in Chrome Browser Console I'm getting:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0"

```
VM353:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):16)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2)
```

1. The following php script reads GPIO values of a Raspberry Pi into a two-dimensional array:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$bcm05 = exec ("gpio -g read 05"); # private comment
$bcm06 = exec ("gpio -g read 06"); # private comment
$bcm16 = exec ("gpio -g read 16"); # private comment
$bcm17 = exec ("gpio -g read 17"); # private comment
$bcm22 = exec ("gpio -g read 22"); # private comment
$bcm23 = exec ("gpio -g read 23"); # private comment
$bcm24 = exec ("gpio -g read 24"); # private comment
$bcm25 = exec ("gpio -g read 25"); # private comment
$bcm26 = exec ("gpio -g read 26"); # private comment
$bcm27 = exec ("gpio -g read 27"); # private comment
$data = array('jq_bcm05' => $bcm05, 'jq_bcm06' => $bcm06, 'jq_bcm16' => $bcm16, 'jq_bcm17' => $bcm17, 'jq_bcm22' => $bcm22, 'jq_bcm23' => $bcm23, 'jq_bcm24' => $bcm24, 'jq_bcm25' => $bcm25, 'jq_bcm26' => $bcm26, 'jq_bcm27' => $bcm27);

$json = json_encode($data, true);
echo $json;
?>
```

2. The echo output of this script is:

```
{"jq_bcm05":"1","jq_bcm06":"0","jq_bcm16":"0","jq_bcm17":"0","jq_bcm22":"0","jq_bcm23":"0","jq_bcm24":"0","jq_bcm25":"0","jq_bcm26":"0","jq_bcm27":"0"}
```

(Note that for some reason the header is not parsed, I've tried various header changes with utf-8, at other places of the code, ... - no luck that it is parsed in the file)

3. With the following html/javascript I'm trying to import the array so that a webpage only refreshes the array vales and not the whole webpage via jquery:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <title>some title</title>
   <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <script src="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>

      <script>
      var php_json_array = "jquery_gpio.php";

      $(document).ready(function(){
         var arr = JSON.parse(php_json_array);
         console.log(arr.jq_bcm05);
      }); 
   </script>
```

4. Also another question:
   I do have "div id" fields in the html page that correspond exactly to the first value of the two-dimensional array. So e.g. there is a  field that I would like to populate with the value "1" from the two-dimensional array.
   I'm too stupid to think a "for each" javascript that does this for each pair that comes from the php script.
   So in the end it should be like

```
<div id="jq_bcm05">1</>
<div id="jq_bcm06">0</>
<div id="jq_bcm17">0</>
<div id="jq_bcm22">0</>
```

... and so on ...

I spent a full day and I'm not getting anywhere. Your help would be deeply appreciated.
Kind regards.

Comment: Open devtools and look at the network tab after you make the request. Inspect the response text and ensure that the JSON is the **only** thing being returned in the request

Comment: You're attempting to decode `jquery_gpio.php` as a string.

Comment: `var php_json_array = "jquery_gpio.php"; var arr = JSON.parse(php_json_array);` -- At no point do you request anything from the server. You're just trying to parse the string `jquery_gpio.php`

Comment: It seems you are parsing string(filename) I guess you have PHP and JS on the same page, then you can access PHP returned data into JS. let us know if this is the case you have.

Comment: Hello mates, thank you for your helpful and superfast responses. The php code sits in a separate file called jquery_gpio.php. I'm sorry about my stupidity, but how do I decode this array correctly, not as a string and request this from the external file? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hello @aynber, I do understand now that I'm loading not a file but a string. How can I parse the echo-return, formatted as reported with json_encode from an external php file? Sorry for my stupidity and thanks for your help.

Comment: @user10104150 I'm guessing you want to call your remote script dynamically, so take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php) for some examples using jQuery. This will basically help you put the output of that script's execution into a JS variable.

Comment: @Jeto Thank you very much! Awesome!